# Circular References in my C# projects

Tags: c#, circular-dependency

I have the following situation:

1. A project `MyCompany.MyProject.Domain` which contains my domain model, and partial classes (such as `Contact`).
2. I want to 'extend' (by partial class, not extension method) my `Contact` class with a property `Slug` which will give me a simple URL friendly text representation of first and last name.
3. I have a string extension method `ToSlug()` in my `Utility` project `MyCompany.MyProject.Utilities` which does exactly what I want in 2).
4. The problem: My `Utility` project is already referencing my `Domain` project which means that I can't get the `Domain` project to see the `Utility` project's `ToSlug()` method without causing circular reference.

I'm not keen on creating another project to solve this, and I really want to keep the `Slug` logic shared.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Is `Slug` an appropriate name here?  Mind expanding on the reasoning behind using that name?  What does it mean?

Comment: The 'circular-reference-problem-c' part in the URL of this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1318123/circular-reference-problem-c) is called a slug. It's basically the technical term for the designating (usually human readable) part in a URL referencing an entity/endpoint in a web application. Mostly used for SEO or to make the URL look better.

Comment: Ok.... well in that case shouldn't `Utility.ToSlug()` be working on something like `ISluggable`?

Comment: No because it doesn't create the actual full URL, it only turns any string into a URL compatible slug format.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your `Utility` project referencing your `MyCompany.MyProject.Domain` seems like a bit of a code smell.  I'm assuming here that these are utilities that specifically work on domain objects--if that's the case, then why don't you include `MyCompany.MyProject.Utilities` within your `Domain` project (naturally, modifying the namespace accordingly)?

In any case, the normal way to break these kinds of dependencies is to abstract what is required by one project into a set of interfaces, and encapsulate those in a separate assembly.  Before doing that though, make sure that what you're doing *conceptually* is the right thing.

In your particular situation though, consider introducing an interface, viz., `INameHolder`:

```
public interface INameHolder
{
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Then `Contact` implements `INameHolder`.  `INameHolder` exists in another assembly, let's call it `MyCompany.MyProject.Domain.Interfaces`.

Then your `Utilities` project references `Interfaces` (*not* `Domain`) and so does `Domain`, but `Interfaces` doesn't reference anything--the circular reference is broken.

Answer (score 2):

copy ToSlug method to Domain project and Delegate Utility's ToSlug call to this new method

Comment: 'Delegate Utility's ToSlug call to this new method' - please clarify? How?

Comment: this was my initial thought also - but I assumed that the domain wasn't shared thus not allowing the library of extension to load. I could have been wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot share the domain (probably right) and it must consume the logic from a shared library then then you really have to introduce a another assembly.

Or you could load the logic at runtime in the domain by reflection in the domain to access the dependent library. Its not hard just breaks compile time checking.

Answer (score 2):

If you're sure about keeping the code in the utility DLL (Eric's answer seems smart to me), then you could create an interface in your utility project, pass that interface as a parameter to your ToSlug method and then have your domain object implement the interface.